# select ajax result and replace in input search PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want select result Ajax request and Replace it on my input.
result display in result div,I want selected one of them and insert to mobile input and hidden results

```
   <form method="post" action="#" class="form-horizontal" id="adduser">
<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mobile</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="mobile" autocomplete="off" />
<div id="result"></div></div>

</div>
<input type="submit"  name="useradd" id="useradd" class="btn btn-block btn-w-m btn-success" value="add">
</form>
```

ajax jquery :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var req = null;
    $('#mobile').on('keyup', function(){
        var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
        if (mobile && mobile.length > 2)
        {
            $('#loading').css('display', 'block');
            if (req)
                req.abort();
            req = $.ajax({
                url : 'ajax.php',
                type : 'POST',
                cache : false,
                data : {
                    mobile : mobile,
                },
                success : function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data)
                    if (data)
                    {
                        $('#loading').css('display', 'none');
                        $("#result").html(data).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('#loading').css('display', 'none');
            $('#result').css('display', 'none');
        }


    });
});
</script>
```

fetch data and return in Ajax.php

```
if(isset($_POST['mobile'])) {
    $user = new User();
    $result = $user->Searchuser($_POST['mobile']);
    $mobiles= array();
    $names = array();
    while ($info = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo $info['firstname'].'-'.$info['mobile'].'<br/>';

    }

}
```

Look this pic :
[image]

I want select Dany and insert that to mobile input

Comment: I can't understand anything from your question apart from code !

Comment: same here! but just by reading your code: I'd be better to only return data to ajax, not complete html.

Comment: You have a syntax error in you php `echo` line as you are missing a quote in `. - '.` as it should be `.' - '.` just after `$info['firstname']`

Comment: I've added an image to better explain the issue